# Python write DateFrame to AWS redshift using psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to update a table in AWS on a daily basis, what I plan to do is to delete data/rows in a public table in AWS using Python psycopg2 first, then insert a python dataframe data into that table.

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

con=psycopg2.connect(dbname= My_Credential.....)
cur = con.cursor()

sql = """
DELETE FROM tableA
"""

cur.execute(sql)
con.commit()
```

the above code can do the delete, but I don't know how to write python code to insert My_Dataframe to the tableA. TableA size is around 1 millions rows to 5 millions, please advise.

Comment: How big is your data set? If you insert with psycopg2 it will be really slow, you can write to S3 and use `copy` command to load to Redshift

Comment: Also based on your requirements, if you need to delete and reload the table on a regular basis you can use `truncate` it will be faster and more advisable

Comment: @mdem7 around 1 millions rows to 5 millions, do you know how to use truncate?

Comment: For that many rows it will be extremely slow if you insert from python, you need to use `copy`. For truncate the syntax is `truncate table tableA`

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what @mdem7 has suggested in comment, inserting 1-5 million data using `dataframe` is not a good idea at all and you will face performance issues.

Its better to use the `S3` to `Redshift` load approach. Here goes your code to do both `Truncate` and `Copy` command.

```
import psycopg2


def redshift():

    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='database_name', host='888888888888****.u.****.redshift.amazonaws.com', port='5439', user='username', password='********')
    cur = conn.cursor();

    cur.execute("truncate table example;")

    //Begin your transaction
    cur.execute("begin;")
    cur.execute("copy example from 's3://examble-bucket/example.csv' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=ID;aws_secret_access_key=KEY/KEY/pL/KEY' csv;")
    ////Commit your transaction
    cur.execute("commit;")
    print("Copy executed fine!")

redshift();
```

There are even more ways to make `Copy` faster in `Menifest` [option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html), so that `Redshift` could load the data in parallel.
Hope this give you some idea to move.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm not familiar with s3, I need to work to engineer to figure how to set this up in order to verify your answer.

Comment: Here you go, about the `S3` https://aws.amazon.com/s3/, also, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading-data-from-S3.html

Answer (score 0):

Any suggestions on, how to pass connection string in place of connection details in below conde : -

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname ='' ,host='' ...) 
i am looking to pass like this ..

conn = psycopg2.connect('Connection_String')
```

Comment: it's better to create a new question for this.